# Bad Operand types for binary operator

Tags: java

Tenho que fazer um exercício para a a faculdade relacionado com vendas e na classe cliente preciso aplicar um método +fazUmaCompra.

Detalhe, realizei até agora apenas a parte "a", coloquei tudo caso ajude na resolução do problema.

código na classe Cliente:

```
public void fazUmaCompra(Compra preco){
    if (preco > 300){
        if (pontos > 2000){
            preco = preco - (preco * 0.05);
            pontos = 0;
        }    
        else if (pontos > 1000){
            preco = preco - (preco * 0.03);
            pontos = pontos -preco / 1;
        }    
        else if (pontos > 500){
            preco = preco - (preco * 0.02);
            pontos = pontos -preco / 1;
        }
        else
            preco = preco;  
}
}
```

EDIT: CLASSE COMPRA

```
public class Compra{
    private String numero;
    private Cliente cliente;
    private Vendedor vendedor;
    private double precoOriginal;
    private double desconto;
    private double preco;

    public Compra(double pO, double ds, double pF, Cliente client){        
        cliente = client;
        String s = cliente.getNome();
        String sub = s.substring(0, 3);
        String num = String.valueOf((int)(Math.random()*10000+100));
        numero = num + sub;
        precoOriginal = pO;
        desconto = ds;
        preco = pF; 
    }
    public Compra(double prO, double dst, double prF, Cliente client, Vendedor vend){
        cliente = client;
        String s = cliente.getNome();
        String sub = s.substring(0, 3);
        String num = String.valueOf((int)(Math.random()*10000+100));
        numero = num + sub;
        precoOriginal = prO;
        desconto = dst;
        preco = prF;
        vendedor = vend;
    }
    public void impoeDesconto(double desct){

    }
    public void setVendedor(Vendedor vend){
        vendedor = vend;
    }
    public void emiteNotaFiscal(){
        System.out.println("Número da Compra: " + numero);
        System.out.println("Nome do Cliente: " + this.cliente.getNome());
        if (vendedor = null)
            vendedor = vendedor;
        else    
        System.out.println("Nome do Vendedor: " + this.vendedor.getNome());
        System.out.println("Preço Inicial: " + precoOriginal);
        System.out.println("Valor do desconto: " + desconto);
        System.out.println("Preço Pago: " + preco);
    }
    public double getPreco(){
        return preco;
    }
}
```

EDIT: CLASSE CLIENTE

```
   private String nome;
    private Endereco endereco;
    private int pontos;

    public Cliente(String nm, Endereco ed){
        nome = nm;
        endereco = ed;
        pontos = 0;
    }
    public Cliente(String nm){
        this.nome = nm;
        this.endereco = new Endereco();
    }
    // alteraEndereco funcionamento errado
    public void alteraEndereco(){
        this.endereco.altera();
    }
    public void fazUmaCompra(Compra preco){
        if (preco.getPreco() > 300){
            if (pontos > 2000){
                preco.getPreco() = preco.getPreco() - (preco.getPreco() * 0.05);
                pontos = 0;
            }    
            else if (pontos > 1000){
                preco.getPreco() = preco.getPreco() - (preco.getPreco() * 0.03);
                pontos = pontos -preco / 1;
            }    
            else if (pontos > 500){
                preco.getPreco() = preco.getPreco() - (preco.getPreco() * 0.02);
                pontos = pontos -preco / 1;
            }
            else
                preco = preco;  
    }
    }
    public String getNome(){
        return nome;
    } 
}
```

O erro occore na linha:

```
if (preco > 300){
```

bad operand types for binary operator '>'

Comment: Onde que `Bad Operand types for binary operator` entra na sua dúvida?

Comment: me desculpe, esqueci de colocar esta informação no post, vou editar.

Comment: Amigo, qual a sua dúvida? afinal não vamos fazer o exercício apenas ajudar onde está o problema.

Comment: Poderia colocar sua classe `Compra` para nós?

Comment: **Compra** *preco* é uma classe correto, então deve ter *preco*.[aqui o campo que você vai saber se e > 300]. Exemplo **preco.getPreco()** > 300, se ta comparando a classe vai dar erro mesmo !!!

Comment: Preco é um objeto  e não uma variável! deveria fazer algo como preco->getValor().

Comment: Fulvio, como eu poderia fazer isso se o atributo preço da classe Compra deve ser privado? um método get talvez?

Comment: @user3511983, utilize get/set nos `private` que deseja expor fora da classe !!!

Comment: Ok fulvio!! muito obrigado

Comment: pontos = pontos -preco / 1; faltou trocar aqui ó

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Compra` é uma classe, e `preco` é uma variável de referência que referencia um objeto da classe `Compra`. Você não pode comparar um objeto com um valor, assim:

```
public void fazUmaCompra(Compra preco){
    if (preco > 300){ //ERRADO
```

Você deve estar querendo pegar algum atributo da classe `Compra` para então comparar com os valores que você deseja, acredito que o atributo que você quer comparar é o `preco`, portanto seu código ficaria:

```
public void fazUmaCompra(Compra preco){
    if (preco.getPreco() > 300){ //CERTO
```

Você deve substituir todas suas comparações de `preco` por `preco.getPreco()` em seu código, pois o compilador parou no primeiro erro, entretanto assim que você consertar o erro o compilador começará a mostrar os demais erros.

**EDIÇÃO**

Lendo melhor seu código vi que seu método `getPreco()` está errado, pois ele retorna um `int` entretanto seu `preco` é double.

```
public int getPreco(){
    return preco;
}
```

Corrija seu get para ficar assim:

```
public double getPreco(){
    return preco;
}
```

Comment: Hmmm estranho... o compilador esta apontando os parenteses de "getPreco()" como unexpected type, required: variable, found: value

Comment: @user3511983 veja minha edição

Comment: já havia localizado esse erro e feito a correção, mas o erro persiste

Comment: @user vou jogar na IDE então, você poderia atualizar seu código na pergunta para ter certeza que estou usando o mais atual?

Comment: claro, editarei agora

Comment: @user3511983 Aqui na IDE eu não consegui reproduzir o erro que você citou. A classe que tem o método `fazUmaCompra` consegue enxergar a classe `Compra`?

Comment: sim, a classe cliente enxerga a classe compra, tanto que existe o método +emiteNotaFiscal na classe Compra que necessita de valor de Cliente

Answer (score 0):

**Exemplo da Classe:**

```
public class Compra {
    /*
     * Construtor
     */
    public Compra() {
    }    
    /*
     * Privates
     */
    private Double preco;    
    /*
     * Get/Set
     */
    public Double getPreco() {
        return preco;
    }

    public void setPreco(Double preco) {
        this.preco = preco;
    }    
}
```

Perceba que o `private Double preco` só é visto no seu escopo, criando seu **Get/Set** (*getPreco e setPreco*), você consegue acessar por eles o seu private preco.

**Usar:**

```
Compra c = new Compra();
c.setPreco(150D);
if (c.getPreco()> 300){

}
```

Comment: Fulvio, qual seria o significado daquele "150D"?

Comment: 150D @user3511983, para ele saber que é double ... se você colocar um número fixo ele pede isso... o valor é 150 !!!

Comment: @user3511983, olhe esse link dos `datatypes`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: olharei, valeu!